# jQuery - select parent within the selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have `$(html).find('.model').parent().text()` which works as expected. Is there a way to express the "parent" relationship within the selector? Neither `$(html).find('.model:parent').text()` nor `$(html).find('.model:parent()').text()` seem to work.

I am passing the selector as an argument, so I want the selector to lead directly to the element. In this case, the parent doesn't have a unique attribute so I can't select it without finding the child first. I have come across the parent selector in docs[1] but can't figure out how to combine it with a class name selector.

[1] https://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/

Comment: We do have a [`:parent`](https://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/) pseudo selector but it's meaning is far different from what you're looking for. The closest would be the [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) pseudo selector.

Comment: As you can read on the linked page, `.model:parent` selects *.model item(s) that themselves are parents of something*. The page gives advice on how to get the kind of parent selection that you want, but only using method calls. Selectors are typically used to drill down on elements, AFAIK they never go back up the hierarchy.

Comment: @PeterKA: Thank you - `:has()` worked! I was able to select the node I want by using `'h1:has(.model)'` since I know it will always be an h1. If you wouldn't mind posting your comment as an answer, I will mark it as as such.

@Peter B: Thank you. My issue was fixed with :has().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`:parent`](https://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/) is not what you're looking for. Perhaps [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) is the closest pseudo selector to what you're looking for.

Usage:

```
$(html).find('*:has(.model)').text();
```

Or more specifically:

```
$(html).find('h1:has(.model)').text();
```